# Заголовки в таблице, с сортировкой данных

Tags: php, html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Представьте себе табличку с данными, у нее есть так называемый заголовок - первая строка с названиями колонок. Интересует как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на заголовок 1 раз таблица сортировала строки по убыванию в столбце, в котором было нажатие, 2-й раз - по возрастанию?

В моем случае табличка получается из цикла while внутри php кода

```
<table>
<tr><td>название</td><td>показатель 1</td><td>показатель 2</td><td>показатель 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>кошка</td><td>5</td><td>45</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>собака</td><td>6</td><td>43</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [Вот поищи)](https://www.google.ru/webhp?rls=ig#hl=ru&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&cp=12&gs_id=1c&xhr=t&q=jquery+datagrid&pf=p&newwindow=1&rls=ig&sclient=psy-ab&oq=jquery+datag&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9cedb7909eef25f8&biw=1360&bih=667)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP тут ни к чему. Если при нажатии, то уже JavaScript. Ну разве что, если таблица огромная.

Решений довольно [много](http://tinyurl.com/c6d5upv). Выбирайте, какое ближе.

Comment: собственно гуголь рулит, просто не знал как правильно спросить 8-) нашел пару решений на JS

Comment: И такое бывает :)